# No puedo subir un archivo por su gran tamaño usando AJAX con Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, archivo, fileupload

Resulta adjunto documentos de lo mas normal con el siguiente codigo:

```
$("#importarRut").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#ajax_loader").css("display", "");

                var fileUpload = $("#file_import").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;
                var archivo = $("#file_import").val();

                var fileData = new FormData();

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                if (files.length == 0) {
                    alert("Debe Adjuntar Excel");
                    return;
                }
                fileData.append("nombreHoja", $("#idnombrehoja").val())
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Nombre/GuardarImportacionRut/',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
                    processData: false, // Not to process data  
                    data: fileData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#ajax_loader").css("display", "none");

                        if (result.retornoJson == "1") {
                            alert('Excel Importado Correctamente');

                        } else {
                            alert("error: " + result.mensajeErrorJson + " linea:" + result.lineaErroJson);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Pero cuando subo un archivo de 102 MB, me sale error [object Objet]. Lo cual concluyo que, por su gran tamaño no lo permite.
En la webconfig puse esto, para intentar de que funcionara:

```
  <requestFiltering>
    <!--<requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />-->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
  </requestFiltering>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Pero aun así, no resulta. ¿Existe alguna posibilidad de habilitar o permitir subir archivos con tamaños grandes?¿o Alguna solución?

Comment: el backend tiene un log de errores, ahi deberia arrojarte el problema real, antes de poder darte una solución válida.

Comment: te refieres al Inspeccionar en el navegador?

Comment: Lo primero sería probar con un valor más alto en maxRequestLength, le pusiste casi el mismo valor del archivo, ponle el doble solo con fines de testeo